# Flink: Are multiple execution environments supported?

Tags: join, apache-flink, environment, flink-streaming

Is it OK to create multiple ExecutionEnvironments in a Flink program? More specifically, create one *ExecutionEnvironment* and one *StreamExecutionEnvironment* in the same main method, so that one can work with batch and later transit to streaming without problems?

I guess that the other possibility would be to split the program in two, but for my testing purposes this seems better. Is Flink prepared for this scenario?

---

All seems to work fine, except I am currently having problems with no output when `join`ing two streams on a common index and using `window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))`. I have already called `setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)` on the StreamExecutionEnvironment and even tried assigning custom watermarks on both joined streams with `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` where I just return `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the timestamp of each record.
Since it finishes really quickly, both streams should fit in that 1-second window, no? Both streams print just fine right before the join. I can try supplying the important parts of code (it's rather lengthy) if anyone's interested.

---

UPDATE: OK, so I separated the two environments (put each inside a *main* method) and then I simply call the first main from the second main method. The described problem no longer occurs.

Comment: Can we create multiple ExecutionEnvironment in one programm..like creating it for thread support ...more than 1...? like following example ```  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
            executor.execute(worker);
          }
        executor.shutdown();  ``` in worker we can multiple instance of ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this not supported, and won't really work.

At least up through Flink 1.9, a given application must either have an ExecutionEnvironment and use the DataSet API, or a StreamExecutionEnvironment and use the DataStream API. You cannot mix the two in one application.

There is ongoing work to more completely unify batch and streaming, but that's a work in progress. To understand this better you might want to watch the video for [this recent Flink Forward talk](https://europe-2019.flink-forward.org/conference-program#towards-flink------unified-batch---stream-processing) when it becomes available.

Comment: So I should separate the environments?

Because I was able to run the program without errors. Just encountered unexpected behavior which I wasn't sure what was the cause of.